# Controlar que no se repitan los correos en base de datos SOLUCIONADO

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, validación

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación con CodeIgniter que es un formulario que recoge los datos y los  inserta en base de datos, lo que el cliente pide ,es que se controle que los emails no se repitan osea, que no los guarde si no que aparezca un mensaje de que este email ya esta registrado, estoy intentándolo hacer por medio de un callback en form validation `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email','callback_email');`

Os dejo el codigo que intente hacer,tanto del controlador y del modelo.

CONTROLLER

```html
    public function email($data){
        $validation= $this->model->validar_mail($data);
        if($validation > 0){
//            $this->form_validation->set_message('mails','Se deben aceptar los términos y condiciones');
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
            }
    }
```

MODLEO

```html
    public function validar_mail($mail){
        $correo="select count(*) as numero from cliente where email = $mail";
        return $this->db->query($correo)->row()->numero;
    }
```

Codigo Solucionado:

controller:

```html
<!-- Validation donde llama al la función del callback -->
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email|callback_verifica');

<!--Funcion del callback -->
public function verifica($mail){
        if($this->empleado_model->existe_mail($mail)){
            $this->form_validation->set_message('verifica','El email introducido ya esta registrado');
            return false;
        }else{

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Modelo:

```html
    public function existe_mail($mail){
        $this->db->select('email');
        $this->db->from('cliente');
        $this->db->where('email', $mail);
        $result = $this->db->get('');

        if (!$result->num_rows() == 1) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y si haces que el campo sea un indice único en la base de datos y controlas el error al grabarlo???

Comment: Hola Anselmo, lo entiendo pero me podrías poner un ejemplo para comprenderlo mejor. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo por medio de form validation o puedes también hacerlo por medio de una función.

1. Recibir los datos (email principalmente)
2. Crear una función en el modelo que seleccione el email si existe y que retorne true si lo encuentra y false si no lo encuentra.
3. Con esto sabras si existe ya en la BD.

Controlador:

```
public function verifica_mail($mail)
{
    // si retorna true es que existe
    if($this->tu_model->existe_mail($mail)){
        // existe
    }else{
        // no existe
    }
}
```

Modelo:

```
public function existe_mail($mail)
{
    $this->db->select('campomail');
    $this->db->from('tutabla');
    $this->db->where('campomail', $mail);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if (!$result->num_rows() == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ya sabiendo si el mail existe ya no lo registras, si no existe procedes a realizar el registro.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, lo he puesto tal cual me has indicado peo sigue sin funcionarme, edito la pregunta para que puedas mirar y me digas si tengo algo mal.

Comment: Debería de funcionarte perfectamente, a menos de que no le estés mandando bien el parámetro a la función te pasara eso. Verifica con `var_dump()` a tu variable para que veas el contenido de la misma y que asegures que tus datos están llegando correctamente.

Comment: Hola Eduardo y Anselmo he logrado resolver el problem, no me funcionaba por que en el callback estaba usando una coma(,) y es una bara ( | ). Pongo la incidencia resulta. Mil gracias